# Pass in custom predicate to TableQuery's filter method

Tags: scala, slick

I am trying to generalize a function to filter out some `TableQuery` in slick using `filter`, so I have created the following method:

```
def fetchCoffee(coffe: String)(p: MyTable => Boolean) =
    // ...
    myTableQuery.filter(p)
    // ...
```

and I called it like this:

```
fetchCoffee("micoffee")(_.coffeeId == id)
```

But it is failing with this error:

```
Error:(43, 29) inferred type arguments [Boolean] do not conform to method filter's type parameter bounds [T <: slick.lifted.Rep[_]]
    val query = MyTable.filter(p)
Error:(43, 36) type mismatch;
 found   : MyTable => Boolean
 required: MyTable => T
    val query = myTableQuery.filter(p)
Error:(43, 35) Type T cannot be a query condition (only Boolean, Rep[Boolean] and Rep[Option[Boolean]] are allowed
    val query = myTableQuery.filter(p)
```

I have tried to change `p`'s type to `p: MyTable => Rep[Boolean]`, and `Rep[MyTable => Boolean]` but still not working. I have also tried to pass in the `ExecutionContext` as implicit to `fetchCoffee` without luck.

How should I write the predicate type to conform with the type bound `T`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `Rep[Boolean]` instead of `Boolean` and `===` instead of `==`.

```
def fetchCoffee(coffe: String)(p: MyTable => Rep[Boolean]) = {
  myTableQuery.filter(p)
}

fetchCoffee("micoffee")(_.coffeeId === id)
```

Comment: @ElBaulP The code compiles https://scastie.scala-lang.org/sLzkjf6hSHSP6VJZiHfjWg

Comment: I am going to try again and see what am I missing.

Comment: It was the missing `import slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._`, `===` wasn't being found because of that missing import.